# how to make Accessibiity pdf from postscript file

Tags: pdf, accessibility, postscript

I came to knew from one thread "ghostscript ps pdfmark command /BDC for content tagging (PDF/UA and WCAG 2.0)" that it is possible to create Accessibility PDF from postscript file. is there any documentation, or any samples provided by any of you to help me understand, how to achieve in that way?

i want to create Accessibility pdf out of postscript files

Comment: The only documentation is the pdfmark documentation, available online https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/library/pdfmark/toc.html though there should also be a PDF of that, which Adobe no longer seem to host (actually, its here https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/pdfs/acrobatsdk_pdfmark.pdf). I should warn you that these pdfmarks conform to PostScript syntax, and must be placed at the correct point throughout the PostScript program, which I think you will find non-trivial.

Comment: If you want to follow a standard, you'll also need the PDF/UA standard, which is an ISO publication, and not free.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations and warnings. Already i have achieved alt-text in postscript file, some five years back and it goes well without any issues in ps to pdf conversion. But for these long period i am searching for a small knot to get into Tagged Pdf features in postscript files. I hope all your inputs would be helpful for my understanding and experimentation

Comment: how much the cost of PDF/UA Standard ISO publication, from where i have to purchase this documentation?

Comment: You do know how to use Google ? The ISO is an international Standards Organisation, you can find it here https://www.iso.org/home.html The PDF/UA specification is (from Wikipedia) formally identified as ISO 14289. Searching the ISO site takes you to https://www.iso.org/standard/82278.html which tells you it costs CHF 173. That's 173 Swiss Francs.